# How to override _onSave function from js in ODOO V14

Tags: javascript, odoo

I want costume JavaScript for "Sale.order" fields. If fields value wrong then save button not trigger.

[image: I want to compare "Total Quantity" and "Consume Quantity" using js If both quantity are the same, then save record else do not save]

[image]

Comment: why you don't try create and write method of ORM instead of using JS?

Comment: You can use [constrains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/fr/developer/reference/orm.html#odoo.api.constrains) to check the fields values each time they are modified.

Comment: @Kenly ,
 i used "constraints", but it does not work on my condition so i used js.
 when I click custome button "constraints" calls
I want only constraints call on save button.

Comment: @HimanshuSharma , 
I know create and write method of ORM .

But i Don,t Know how to used js in Odoo.

Can you give me one Example for fields compair (like Qty and other Qty) using js.

Comment: Please give some more details what you want to achieve so we can give suggestion(s) (OOTB).

Comment: @HimanshuSharma , I add Two Screen shot above,
In 1st Screen "Total Quantity" And 2ed Screen "Consume Quantity".
I Want compare both Quantity Using js
 If Both Quantity same then record save else not save.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the custom form view controller (set using the special [js_class](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/fr/developer/reference/javascript_cheatsheet.html?highlight=js_class#customizing-an-existing-view) attribute) to include a custom `_onSave` function.

***Example:***

```js
odoo.define('module_name.FormController', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var SaleOrderView = require('sale.SaleOrderView');
    
    SaleOrderView.prototype.config.Controller.include({
        _onSave: function (recordID, options) {
            var self = this;
            // var values = self.renderer.state.data;
            // var order_line = values.order_line.data
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        },
    });

});
```